# Reusing Attributed Element Data to Build List Automatically

Tags: xml, xsd, reusability

Fellow forum Members, 
I would appreciate any help.

`<acronym acronymtype="at01">
<acronymTerm>MOMA</acronymTerm>
<acronymDefinition id="acr-0001">Museum Of Modern Art</acronymDefinition>
</acronym>`

The code above is an example of how the S1000D standard handles acronyms. My objective is to figure out what XML code functions as a lasso that retrieves the attribute acronymtype="at01" found within a lot of data modules and collects all of this attributed acronym element data in one common data module I'm calling "List Of Acronyms".  In other words, what XML mechanism should I be looking at if I want to reuse attributed data residing within many data modules and have it automatically gathered and reused in one common data module? I want to avoid the work of manually gathering all of the different acronyms residing within many data modules and building an acronym list manually. My goal is for my Acronym List to auto generate.  Is this possible with Issue 4.01 of the S1000D schema?  Any hints, help, tips greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please clarify - there is no 'XML code'. Do you mean XSLT? Which kind of output are you looking for?

Comment: It's easy to generate a list of all the acronyms (at least, all the acronyms tagged using the `acronym` element) from XML tagged as you show.  How you go about it depends on what you are using (or what you want to use) to process the XML; if your organization already has a commitment to a particular tool chain, you need to find out what that tool chain is and ask how to do what you need to do with the tools you need to use.  If you don't have a tool chain yet, you will want to learn about XSLT and XQuery.